# How to execute an application uploaded to worker nodes with --files option?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am uploading a file to my worker nodes using spark-submit, and I would like to access this file. This file is a binary, which I would like to execute. I already know how to execute the file through scala, but I keep getting a "File not found" exception and I can't find a way to access it.

I use the following command to submit my job.

```
spark-submit --class Main --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --files las2las myjar.jar
```

when the job is being executed I noticed that it was uploaded to the staging directory for the current running application, when I tried to run the following, it didn't work.

```
val command = "hdfs://url/user/username/.sparkStaging/" + sparkContext.applicationId + "/las2las" !!
```

This is the exception that gets thrown:

```
17/10/22 18:15:57 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hdfs://url/user/username/.sparkStaging/application_1486393309284_26788/las2las": error=2, No such file or directory
```

So, my question is, how can I access the las2las file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SparkFiles`:

```
 val path = org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get("las2las")
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I access the las2las file?

When you go to the YARN UI at http://localhost:8088/cluster and click on the application **ID** for the Spark application, you'll get redirected to the page with the container logs. Click **Logs**. In **stderr** you should find lines that looks similar to the following:

```
===============================================================================
YARN executor launch context:
  env:
    CLASSPATH -> {{PWD}}<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_conf__<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_libs__/*<CPS>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark_conf__/__hadoop_conf__
    SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> file:/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0002
    SPARK_USER -> jacek
    SPARK_YARN_MODE -> true

  command:
    {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java \ 
      -server \ 
      -Xmx1024m \ 
      -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp \ 
      '-Dspark.worker.ui.port=44444' \ 
      '-Dspark.driver.port=55365' \ 
      -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> \ 
      -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' \ 
      org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend \ 
      --driver-url \ 
      spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@192.168.1.6:55365 \ 
      --executor-id \ 
      <executorId> \ 
      --hostname \ 
      <hostname> \ 
      --cores \ 
      1 \ 
      --app-id \ 
      application_1508700955259_0002 \ 
      --user-class-path \ 
      file:$PWD/__app__.jar \ 
      1><LOG_DIR>/stdout \ 
      2><LOG_DIR>/stderr

  resources:
    __spark_libs__ -> resource { scheme: "file" port: -1 file: "/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0002/__spark_libs__618005180363157241.zip" } size: 218111116 timestamp: 1508701349000 type: ARCHIVE visibility: PRIVATE
    __spark_conf__ -> resource { scheme: "file" port: -1 file: "/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0002/__spark_conf__.zip" } size: 105328 timestamp: 1508701349000 type: ARCHIVE visibility: PRIVATE
    hello.sh -> resource { scheme: "file" port: -1 file: "/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0002/hello.sh" } size: 33 timestamp: 1508701349000 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
===============================================================================
```

I executed my Spark application as follows:

```
YARN_CONF_DIR=/tmp \
./bin/spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client --files hello.sh
```

so the lines of interest is:

```
hello.sh -> resource { scheme: "file" port: -1 file: "/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0002/hello.sh" } size: 33 timestamp: 1508701349000 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE
```

You should find a similar line with the path to the shell script (mine is `/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0002/hello.sh`).

> This file is a binary, which I would like to execute.

With the line, you can try to execute it.

```
import scala.sys.process._
scala> s"/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/${sc.applicationId}/hello.sh" !!
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0003/hello.sh": error=13, Permission denied
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:113)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:129)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
  ... 50 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
  ... 54 more
```

It won't work by default since the file is not marked as executable.

```
$ ls -l /Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0003/hello.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 jacek  staff  33 22 paź 21:51 /Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0003/hello.sh
```

(I don't know if you can inform Spark or YARN to make a file executable).

Let's make the file executable.

```
scala> s"chmod +x /Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/${sc.applicationId}/hello.sh".!!
res2: String = ""
```

It is indeed an executable shell script.

```
$ ls -l /Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0003/hello.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jacek  staff  33 22 paź 21:51 /Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/application_1508700955259_0003/hello.sh
```

Let's execute it then.

```
scala> s"/Users/jacek/.sparkStaging/${sc.applicationId}/hello.sh".!!
+ echo 'Hello world'
res3: String =
"Hello world
"
```

It worked fine given the following `hello.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

echo "Hello world"
```